# Java webapp produces StackOverflow exception on Linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, web, stack-overflow

I have a Java-web application running on Tomcat 9. It works fine on a Windowns machine. But after deploying this app on a Debian Linux server I've encountered java.lang.StackOverflow exceptions on some particular pages. Here is the beginning of the stacktrace log:

```
27-Dec-2017 08:54:43.746 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-3] 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke Servlet.service() for 
servlet [jsp] threw exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize(UnixFileSystem.java:172)
at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractFileResourceSet.file(AbstractFileResourceSet.java:90)
```

**Please, see full stacktrace here:**
https://pastebin.com/0AmFDY8F

As far as I understand, the exception occurs while compiling the JSP page source by Jasper and it's somehow related to the resolving of Linux paths / directories. Could anybody please help me to figure out what the exact problem is? I didn't create any symbolic links, if the problem can be related to this.

Comment: Even if you don't have any symbolic links, you might want to also [look for hard links](https://superuser.com/questions/485919/how-can-i-find-all-hardlinked-files-on-a-filesystem) on your file system.

Comment: Don't know if this could be related, but make sure you are using right file and path as Linux/Unix is case sensitive, not Windows.

Comment: @azurefrog how could hard links be related to this problem? I checked the hard links on my system: there is nothing among them concerning my webapp.

Comment: It would have been another way that you could have had a circular path in your file system.  I can't think of another way you'd get a a stack overflow trying to do something as basic as getting a canonical path to a file.

Comment: @Alexandre Lavoie everything is ok here. The problem doesn't seem to be related to this.

Comment: Please add more information about your development and deployment environments. JDK and Tomcat version on each? Debian version? Did you check the permissions on the filesystem in the deployment environment? Etc.

Comment: @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy Windows: Windows 7, Java 1.8.0_31 x64, Tomcat 9.0.0.M22.
Linux: Debian 9.3.0 stretch (x64), Java 1.8.0_151, Tomcat 9.0.2. Yeah, I checked the permissions.

Comment: @Kaori Can you provide the code that is causing the exception and maybe a few lines before and after for context? Why do you need the canonical path?

Comment: @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy I don't know which code causes the exception. I have no idea why the canonical path is needed.

Answer (score 0):

According to your stack trace, the problem is caused by not being able to find a specific path as resolved by your Spring framework:

> org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: JSPException including path '/struct/context/tutorials.jsp'.

The Spring framework is likely using the canonical paths to resolve the file, and it fails perhaps because there is some quirk in the framework related to the type of Unix system you are deploying to.

Please reference this in the Spring documentation:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-install-supported-operating-systems

> The default script supports most Linux distributions and is tested on CentOS and Ubuntu. Other platforms, such as OS X and FreeBSD, will require the use of a custom embeddedLaunchScript.

Notice that Debian was not listed. Hopefully this puts you on the right path.
If I'm chasing a red herring here, I'm sorry - but you haven't given us much to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found what caused the StackOverflow exception. I have a recursive JSP tag call to render nested options for a `<select>` tag. After removing the recursion, the exception disappeared. Sure, it's just a workaround, so I'm still wondering why it works fine on Windows and doesn't on Linux.